# Magento get product variations/options with PHP

Tags: php, magento, product, mage

I am trying to get product variations for each child product on the view.phtml page.

Essentially, the drop-down of options for a configurable product are made of these values.  For example - A t-shirt might have 3 sizes: small, medium, and large.  The drop-down list that Magento has built-in, shows these 3 options (children products).

I am looking for the code to get these options.

I apologize if this is not very clear, the terminology for the Magento products is confusing.  Just let me know if you need more details clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while. But I had similar problem while creating a script to export products a long with its children, options and prices.

This should get you started: http://fuckyeahcoding.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/easy-magento-csv-product-feeds/